# add class if date is today

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some boxes that represent the squares in an advent calendar. I've defined the date for each box in the data attribute which I'm using to compare against the current day. I'm trying to add a class 'today' to the box that represents the current day. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate this. How can I fix it so that today class is added to the appropriate box?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycvdv3qx/)

```
$(function() {
var currentDate = Date.now();

$(".grid-item").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
    var date = Date.parse(specifiedDate);

    if (!isNaN(date) == currentDate) {
        $(this).addClass('today');
    }
    else if(!isNaN(date) && currentDate - date > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('past');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('future');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: The problem is that Date.now() returns a timestamp. Your dates are without the time part. Round it up to whole days and it will work.

Comment: Take a look at [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Great, thanks that's really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `Date.now()` as this doesn't outputs the dates similar to the `data` attributes have. Instead you have to create current date as this and check in the conditions like:

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date(),
    currentDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
  $(".grid-item").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
    if (specifiedDate == currentDate) {
      $(this).addClass('today');
    } else if (currentDate > specifiedDate) {
      $(this).addClass('past');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('future');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.today {
  background: yellow;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
.past {
  background: black;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
.future {
  background: blue;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-23">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-24">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-25">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-26">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-27">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-28">
</div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-11-29">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. It's no longer working. Any idea why? You can refer to the latest fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jrnvzrfu/

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/ycvdv3qx/11/) JSFiddle

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var currentDate = Date.parse((new Date()).toLocaleDateString());

    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
        var date = Date.parse(specifiedDate);

        if (!isNaN(date) && date == currentDate) {
            $(this).addClass('today');
        }
        else if(!isNaN(date) && currentDate - date > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('past');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('future');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works in Chrome but not FF or IE on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to current date using following jquery, just replace your jquery with following :-

```
$(function() {
    var d =new Date();
    var curmonth = d.getMonth()+1;
    var curDate = d.getFullYear()+"-"+curmonth+"-"+d.getDate();

    $(".grid-item[data-date="+curDate+"]").addClass("today");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycvdv3qx/6/)

```
$(function() {
    var currentDate = Date.now();
    var a = new Date(currentDate);
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
        var date = Date.parse(specifiedDate);
        var b = new Date(date);
        if (!isNaN(b) && b.getMonth() == a.getMonth() && b.getDay()== a.getDay() && b.getYear() == a.getYear()) {
            $(this).addClass('today');
        }
        else if(!isNaN(b) && a - b > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('past');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('future');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a single mistake in your code. `Date.now()` gives you the current timestamp in milliseconds. While you have a date in the `data-date` which will not match in any case. **Correct way will be to compare the date instead of timestamps**. **Or just take the date without the time for comparison**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to create `new Date()` object, and set it's hours, minutes and seconds to 0 like that:

```
currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0);
currentDate.setMinutes(0);
currentDate.setSeconds(0);
```

and then:

```
var date = new Date(specifiedDate);
date.setHours(0);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
```

Note that I am also setting `date`'s hours, minutes and second to 0 due timezones (this can be fixed, but as I said, it seems to be the easiest way)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use :

```
$(function() {
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {

        $('.grid-item').eq(new Date().getDay()-1).addClass('today');

    });
 });
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ycvdv3qx/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
$(function() {
var currentDate = new Date();

$(".grid-item").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
    var date = new Date(specifiedDate);

    if(date.setHours(0,0,0,0) == currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)){

        $(this).addClass('today');
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me last day. hope this helps you..

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

if (date == today) {
    $(this).addClass('today');
}
```

make sure two dates are same format..