# Add jquery Class if the date is today

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

i could not able to find the right answer on the net regarding adding class if current date is today.

I have a list of events and i want to add class to the event date, if it matches today.

Output

```
12  13 September 2018   Thursday    Workout
2   22 September 2018   Saturday    Workout <-- today
1   25 September 2018   Tuesday     Meeting
3   06 October 2018     Saturday    Meeting
13  11 October 2018     Thursday    Meeting
4   22 October 2018     Monday      Workout
7   27 October 2018     Saturday    Meeting
5   05 November 2018    Monday      Workout
14  07 November 2018    Wednesday   Meeting
```

HTML

```
<table class="calendar">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Item</th>
    </thead>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
        $cId = $row['c_id'];
        $cDate = $row['c_datetime'];
        $ciName = $row['ci_name'];
        $ccName = $row['cc_name'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $cId; ?></td>
            <td class="day"><?php echo dateFormatFullMonth($cDate); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo dateFormatDay($cDate); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ciName; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

This one below, matches the day.

```
$('table.calendar tr td.day').eq(new Date().getDay()).parent().addClass('bg-success');
```

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas Updated the code.

Comment: Thank you, but you're showing PHP - which is irrelevant once the code is at the client. So, unless you're using [tag:node.js], you need to post the "*[mcve]*" code that the browser receives.

Comment: @DavidThomas updated with Output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be explaining things really badly. Your jQuery shows that you have a `<table>` element? Please post the code of that `<table>` (if that's the relevant HTML). View Source -> copy & paste the element's HTML, or 'right click' -> 'Inspect element' -> right click the DOM Node in the inspector -> copy -> copy outerHTML.

Comment: Is `dataFormatFullMonth` a defined function in php? The key will be matching the format of the php date with the JavaScript data. If when stringified the formats are different, you will have trouble.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's not necessary. If he is using php, he needs to include all his php function definitions, and make this a php plus jQuery/JavaScript question. Ultimately, the answer comes down to comparing the stringified values of the two differing date functions, between PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: @TheHive I don't understand, why don't you implement it with php? using `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');` & `$now = new DateTime();` to check the current date and print out classname using `echo`, shouldn't that be much easier?

Comment: @JaniceZhong. hmm.. i think i'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @TheHive No worries, I'm glad to help if you need further help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935926/5413283

```
<!-- Today is 25 Sep 18 -->
<div id="datecontainer">
    <p data-date="2018-9-20">2018-09-20</p>
    <p data-date="2018-9-21">2018-09-21</p>
    <p data-date="2018-9-22">2018-09-22</p>
    <p data-date="2018-9-23">2018-09-23</p>
    <p data-date="2018-9-24">2018-09-24</p>
    <p data-date="2018-9-25">2018-09-25</p> <!-- this will have the class -->
</div>

$(function() {
    var d =new Date();
    var curmonth = d.getMonth()+1;
    var curDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + curmonth + "-" +d.getDate();
    $("#datecontainer p[data-date="+curDate+"]").addClass("today");
});
```

And for two digit month

```
var curDate = d.getFullYear() + "-0" + curmonth + "-" +d.getDate();
```